# Combinatorial Proof for the Number of Squares in a Grid

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, programming

I am exploring combinatorial methods to solve a problem related to counting the number of squares in a grid. Given an 'a x b' grid of evenly spaced points, I want to understand how to determine the total number of squares that can be formed in the grid. I solved the problem with programming with basic loops, but was wondering if there is a more elegant math solution.

First example: 15 squares with a length of 1

[image: grid1]

Second example: 8 squares with a length of 2

[image]

Third case: 3 squares with a length of 3

[image]

So in this case the grid is a = 4, b = 6, 4x6 grid and the sum of all squares would be 26.

I would appreciate any insights, explanations, or resources on combinatorial methods for counting squares in such grids.

Comment: What about "tilted" squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the $3x5$ grid provided $3 \times 5$ squares of size 2, $2 \times 4$ squares of size 2, and $1 \times 3$ squares of size 2.

There's 2 key observations to make: 
(1) Given the smaller dimension of the grid ($n=3$), we can create squares up to size $3$. 
(2) Given the dimensions of the grid ($a \times b$), the number of squares of size $n$ can be determined by $(a-n+1) \times (b-n+1)$.

This means that given a $a \times b$ grid, we can calculate the total number of squares as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (a-i+1) \times (b-i+1)$$
where $n = \min(a,b)$.

Comment: Why does this work? How should I imagine it visually? So we add up 3*5 = 15, 2*4 = 8 and 1*3 = 3 to get 26. I can see why the first one 3*5 = 15 would work, so 3 lines of squares each 1x1 big over the width of 5. How should I imagine it for 2x2 and higher dimensions?

Comment: @AljazBrodar You can imagine 1x1 squares starting on the 1st row and shifting over until it reaches the right side of the grid. Then, you restart at the 2nd row and continue this process, which would occur 3 (num rows) * 5 (num columns) = 15 times. Similarly for 2x2 squares, you can imagine it starting in rows 1/2 then shifting over until it reaches the right side of the grid. It can shift from columns 1/2 to 2/3 to ... to a-1/a which means it shifts a-1 times. Then, you move it down from rows 1/2 to rows 2/3 when you restart, which means you can shift it down b-1 times.

Comment: Essentially, you need to consider the number of times the square can shift from left to right and the number of times the square can shift from top to bottom. Multiplying these together will allow you to calculate the number of squares of any size. Then, the summation will calculate the number of squares of size 1, 2, ..., n to consider each size square.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(a,b)$ for the number of (axes-aligned!) squares in an $a\times b$ grid. By symmetry, $f(b,a)=f(a,b)$, hence it suffices to compute $f(a,b)$ for the case that $b\ge a$.
In that case, we note that $f(a,b+1)-f(a,b)$ does not depend on $b$: It is the number of squares with at least one (and hence exactly two) vertices in the last row. As there are $\binom a2$ ways to pick two out of $a$ vertices, we conclude that $f(a,b)$ is a linear function of $b$ (provided $b\ge a$), namely
$$\tag1 f(a,b)=\binom a2b+c(a)$$
with an offset $c(a)$ that depends only on $a$.
We find $c(a)$ by adjusting it so that $(1)$ gives the correct answer when $b=a$, i.e., for a square grid.

In an $a\times a$ grid, we find one square of side length $a-1$, four squares of side length $a-2$, and more generally $k^2$ squares of side length $a-k$ (as can be shown by checking which grid points can  be the top left vertex of such a square).
With the well-known formula for the sum of squares, this makes
$$\tag2f(a,a)=1^2+2^2+3^3+\cdots +(a-1)^2=\frac{(a-1)a(2a-1)}6.$$
From $(2)$ and $(1)$, we quickly find $c(a)=\frac{a-a^3}6$, hence ultimately
$$ f(a,b)=\frac{a(a-1)(3b-a-1)}6\qquad\text{if }b\ge a.$$